# Is it possible to obtain the _raw_/_unprocessed_ command line?

Tags: winapi, command-line, command-line-arguments

The windows API provides GetCommandLine() which returns the *cooked* command line used to start a process.

For instance, if a console application is started with the command:

> MyProg.exe > OutputHere

The command line seen by MyProg.exe will *not* include the portion

> **> OutputHere**

I'd like to *somehow* get the command line exactly as it was. **Is this possible ? and if yes, how ?**

Suggestions in C and/or plain (no objects) Delphi greatly appreciated.  Creative solutions welcome (hopefully, not requiring ring 0 code.)

Thank you very much for your help.

**NOTE:** I can tell if the input/output, etc has been redirected but, that is not what I'm looking for.  I need the original/uncooked command line.

Comment: If the user puts a redirection via ">", this is *not* part of the command line your application should be able to see. Filtering/redirection characters like > | and whatever are not visible to the application because they are not part of the command line.

Comment: @ Michael, I don't understand.  When the user uses ">" to redirect the output, I never see the ">".  Did I miss your point ?  Now, I see your point.  Never mind.  I still need the command line as the user typed/specified it.

Comment: When the user uses >, this is not part of the "command line" the application sees. It' s read by CMD.EXE in order to create a redirection. Your application cannot (and shoult not) see that redirection if it uses stdout. I don't also see the meaning of all this, why do you want the redirection information? If you don't like redirection, don't use stdout anyway, but create our own output window.

Comment: @ Michael, do you know if there is a way of getting that command line out of cmd.exe ?

Comment: A final suggestion: forget anything that won't work in Windows, especially what comes from Linux. Windows programming is way different than anything command-line related.

Comment: @ Michael, thank you.  I appreciate the suggestions but, I do need the uncooked command line.

Comment: It only exists within cmd.exe.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur: There's no way of doing it. I mean, you *could* detect the parent `cmd.exe` process, then reverse-engineer it to read the entire command line from its memory **if it still exists**, but that's not guaranteed to work in any way, will break from one version of `cmd.exe` to another, and requires enormous amount of work.

Comment: @ Jonathan & ybungalobill, I'm afraid that both of you are very likely right.

Comment: yes, this string ( `MyProg.exe > OutputHere`) view (read from console) only *cmd.exe* he interpret this string as commamd execute *MyProg.exe* with redirected output to *OutputHere*. so it create file by name *OutputHere* and pass handle to this file to your program via `STARTUPINFO.hStdOutput` (you can get this handle and query it name if want), but when call `CreateProcess` *cmd.exe* already not pass `> OutputHere` in command line - it already process this. as result you and can not see this. so you view original command line as is

Comment: Apparently someone didn't like my asking a question they don't have an answer for and voted me down... awwww.  LOL

Comment: Questions on stack overflow are voted down mainly because they show no research effort, not because they cannot be answered.

Comment: @ Michael, you've helped me in the past and I have a great deal of appreciation for the help you've given me.  I want to make something _crystal clear_, that is, before I ask a question here, I have usually spent a number of hours researching and trying everything that comes to mind.  There are some quite accurate words to describe such people but, they would, like the people who voted the question down, be out of place.

Comment: This looks like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The redirection or piping of stdin, stdout and stderr is handled the command interpreter, typically cmd.exe. The interpreter parses the command and creates the necessary files and pipes, and then creates the one or more processes needed to implement your command.

The processes that are created have no knowledge of the original command, they only get that part of the command that is not related to piping and redirection.

So what you are trying to do is not possible, at least within your process. The only thing that knows the original command is the command interpreter.

Comment: @ David, thank you for your help.  I appreciate it. I was worried there would be no way to get the original command line but, I thought I'd ask very knowledgeable people in case I missed something.  One thing the question made evident is that, there are knowledgeable people and some "not so knowledgeable"... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you can retrieve the full command line including the pipe commands depends on whether your start the program in a command window or for example using the "Run" command from the Start menu. If you use the "Run" command from the Start menu `GetCommandLine` actually retrieves the full command line including the redirection commands, but redirection does not work as it seems to be a feature of CMD.EXE.

As others have pointed out, what are you trying to achieve here / why do you need to capture the redirection commands?

Comment: @ Olaff, thank you for that comment.  I've already solved the problem.  Contrary to very popular belief, it is possible to retrieve the uncooked command line. I had not thought about what happens when using the "run" command.  I'll have to look into that one and, from what you've pointed out, I'll likely have to "adapt" to that situation.  Thank you for pointing that out, I had completely forgotten about the "run" command.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur: Could you please share with us how you managed to solve your problem?

Comment: @ Olaf, I was hoping no one would ask because now I'm in a bind.  I enjoy helping and answering people's questions.  I have been quite disappointed by the reaction of some users on this question, I'm referring to those who find it easier to vote it down than to think about the problem and how it could be solved and, the pseudo-intellectuals flaunting their "Cartesian aptitudes". The presumption that I come here and ask a question without first thoroughly researching it for an answer didn't please me much either.  I do give credit to those who sincerely tried to help.

Comment: @ Olaf, the bottom line is, I won't answer the question but, I can tell you without any doubt whatsoever that it is possible since I now have a program that gets the raw command line _reliably_.  Now that you know that it is possible, I will also say that there is no doubt in my mind that everyone who tried to help has all the knowledge necessary to figure out the answer.  The hard part is thinking about it.  That's is the extent of the answer I will provide.  For a more complete answer, those who voted the question down can hopefully provide one since they seem to know it.